# Proof Exercise in Steps in commutative algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, artinian

I am trying to solve this exercise from Sharp's book *Steps in Commutative Algebra*:

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated Artinian module over the
> commutative ring $R$. Show that $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is an Artinian ring.

It is easy to show that if $M$ is a Noetherian $R$-module then $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is a Noetherian ring, but I can't prove the result for Artinian modules.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m_1,\dots,m_k$ be a set of generators for $M$; then $\operatorname{Ann} M=\bigcap_{i=1}^k\operatorname{Ann} m_i$. We prove the desired result by induction on $k$. If $k=1$, then $R\big/\operatorname{Ann}M\cong M$ as $R$-modules via the map $\bar{r}\mapsto rm_1$, so the result is clear. Thus assume $k>1$. Since submodules of Artinian modules are Artinian, the submodule $N:=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}Rm_i$ of $M$ is Artinian, and hence by the inductive hypothesis $R\big/\operatorname{Ann}N$ is Artinian. Also, by the case $k=1$, $R\big/\operatorname{Ann}m_k$ is Artinian. Hence by Lemma 2 the quotient of $R$ by $\operatorname{Ann}N\cap \operatorname{Ann}m_k$ is Artinian. But this latter intersection is simply $\operatorname{Ann}M$, so the result follows.

---

**Lemma 1:** If $N\leqslant M$ are $R$-modules and both $N$ and $M\big/N$ are Artinian, then $M$ is Artinian.

**Proof:** Suppose $M$ is not Artinian, and let $$M=M_0>M_1>M_2>\dots$$ be any strictly descending chain of submodules of $M$. This chain naturally induces descending chains
\begin{align}
N&=N_0\geqslant N_1\geqslant N_2\geqslant\dots \\
M\big/N&=\bar{M}_0\geqslant\bar{M}_1\geqslant\bar{M}_2\geqslant\dots,
\end{align} where $N_i=M_i\cap N$ and $\bar{M}_i=(M_i+N)\big/N$. Since $N$ and $M\big/N$ are Artinian, there must exist some $k$ where the chains above stabilize, ie such that $N_l=N_k$ and $\bar{M}_l=\bar{M}_k$ for each $l\geqslant k$. In particular, $M_{k+1}\cap N=M_k\cap N$ and $M_{k+1}+N=M_k+N$. But now
\begin{align}
M_{k+1}&=M_{k+1}\cap (M_{k+1}+N) \\
&=M_{k+1}\cap (M_{k}+N) \\
&= M_k+(M_{k+1}\cap N) \\
&= M_k+(M_{k}\cap N)=M_k,
\end{align} where the third equality follows from the "[modular law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice)". This is a contradiction, so we are done. $\blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 2:** If $I,J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $R\big/I$ and $R\big/J$ are Artinian, then $R\big/(I\cap J)$ is Artinian.

**Proof:** Let $M=R\big/(I\cap J)$ and let $N$ be the submodule $I\big/(I\cap J)$ of $M$. Note that $M\big/N\cong R\big/I$, which is Artinian, and that $N\cong (I+J)\big/J$, which is a submodule of the Artinian module $R\big/J$ and hence Artinian. So by Lemma 1 $M$ is Artinian, as desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I don't know why $Ann(M)=\cap ann(m_i)$

Comment: dear @jenny, since each $m_i\in M$, we have $\operatorname{Ann}M\subseteq \operatorname{Ann} m_i$ for each $i$ and hence $\operatorname{Ann}\subseteq\bigcap_i\operatorname{Ann} m_i$. for the other direction, suppose $r\in \bigcap_i\operatorname{Ann} m_i$, and let $m\in M$ be arbitrary. since the $m_i$ are generators for $M$, we have $m=r_1m_1+\dots+r_km_k$ for some $r_i\in R$. but $rm_i=0$ for each $i$, hence $rr_im_i=0$ for each $i$, hence $rm=0$, as desired

Comment: Thank you so much for the thoughtful answer. But I don't really understand Artin. So, there are a lot of problem:

1) Can you explain "If $k=1$, then $R/AnnM\cong M$ as $R-$modules via the map $r¯\longmapsto rm_1$". 
 
2) Why "By the case $k=1$, $R/Ann(m_k)$ is Artinian". 

3) Where do u use Lemma 1?

Hope you can explain.

Comment: dear @jenny, my pleasure! :) for question 1; in this case, we have $M=Rm_1$, so $\operatorname{Ann}M=\operatorname{Ann} m_1$. you can check that the map $R\to M$ defined by $r\mapsto rm_1$ is an $R$-module homomorphism; it is surjective since $M=Rm_1$, and its kernel is $\operatorname{Ann}m_1=\operatorname{Ann}M$, and so Noether's [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(modules)) isomorphism theorem tells us that $R\big/\operatorname{Ann}M\cong Rm_1=M$. since $M$ is Artinian by hypothesis, so is $R\big/\operatorname{Ann}M$, as desired

Comment: @jenny for question 2, what we have shown in the case $k=1$, which is covered also in comment I've just written, is that, for any cyclic $R$-module $L$, ie an $R$-module in which $L=Rm$ for some $m\in L$, if $L$ is Artinian then so is $R\big/\operatorname{Ann}L$. but $\operatorname{Ann}L=\operatorname{Ann}m$ in this case, so in the case you're asking about taking $L=Rm_k$ gives us the desired result. (note that $Rm_k$ is a submodule of the Artinian module $M$ and hence Artinian)

Comment: @jenny for question 3, I use Lemma 1 in order to prove Lemma 2. I hope this helps! :)